# Finding the range of a function defined as an integral

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The task is to determine the range of the function

$$ f(x) = \int_x^{2x} \frac{e^{-xt^2}}{t}dt, \;\; x>0 $$

and I have tried to do this by studying its derivative in hopes of finding critical points.
I differentiate it by introducing an auxiliary function

$$ g(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \int_{x_3}^{x_2} \frac{e^{-x_1t^2}}{t}dt $$

so that $f(x) = g(x,2x,x)$. I compute the total derivative of f by using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and by differentiating under the integral sign:

$$\frac{d}{dx} g(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x} $$

$$= \int_{x_3}^{x_2} -te^{x_1 t^2}dt +2\frac{e^{-x_2^2x_1}}{x_2} -\frac{e^{-x_3^2x_1}}{x_3} $$

so
$$f'(x)=-\int_{x}^{2x} te^{-t^2x}dt + \frac{e^{-4x^3}}{x}-\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x}  $$

Next, I compute the integral in the expression for $f'(x)$:
$$ -\int_{x}^{2x}te^{-t^2x}dt = \frac{1}{2x}\int_{x}^{2x}(-2xt)e^{-t^2x}dt = \frac{1}{2x}\left[ e^{-t^2x} \right]_x^{2x} \\
= \frac{1}{2x}(e^{-4x^3}-e^{-x^3} ) $$

so it turns out $f'(x) = \frac{3}{2x}(e^{-4x^3}-e^{-x^3}) $, but this does not have a root that is not also a singular point (let me know if I am using the wrong terms). I do not have any other ideas for how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's change the variable of integration to $u=\frac{t}{x}$; then
$$
f(x)=\int_1^2\frac{e^{-x^3u^2}}{u}\,du.
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\int_1^2\frac{du}{u}=\ln 2
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0.
$$
Since $f'(x)=\frac{3}{2x}(e^{-4x^3}-e^{-x^3})<0$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$, $f$ is a monotonically decreasing function. Therefore, we conclude that its image is the interval $(0,\ln 2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^{-4x^3} \leq e^{-xt^2} \leq e^{-x^3}$ for all $t \in [x,2x],$ you have
$$e^{-4x^3} \ln 2 = e^{-4x^3} \int_x^{2x} \frac{dt}{t} \leq f(x) \leq e^{-x^3} \int_x^{2x} \frac{dt}{t} = e^{-x^3} \ln 2 \qquad \text{for all } x > 0.$$
The above inequality and the continuity of $f$ imply that $\operatorname{Im} f = (0,\ln2).$